# Intuit Quickbooks Online API - How to get purchases

Tags: c#, .net, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I'm using Intuit's .NET SDK for QBO, and am attempting to get a list of purchases from my qbo account. Here's my C# code...

```
var qboCashPurchaseQuery = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.CashPurchaseQuery();
qboCashPurchaseQuery.PageNumber = 1;
qboCashPurchaseQuery.ResultsPerPage = 100;
var results = qboCashPurchaseQuery.ExecuteQuery<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.CashPurchase(context).ToList();
grdQuickBooksCustomers.DataSource = results;
```

I get a table with the number of records matching the number of purchases I expect, but the actual data returned is not what I need.

This is the columns and the first row of data I get back: (sorry for the formatting)

```
SyncToken   Synchronized   IdsType
0                          Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo
```

This bit of code returns the same kind of weird data for some other functions such as InvoiceQuery. What am I doing wrong here to get this data? How might I actually return the detailed purchase data I need?

Answer (score 2):

```
string q = "Select * from Purchase Where PaymentType='Cash' STARTPOSITION 1 MAXRESULTS 100";
dynamic Purchaselist = purchaseQueryService.ExecuteIdsQuery(q);
CashPurchase cashpurchase = new CashPurchase();

foreach (CashPurchase oCash in Purchaselist) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work best for my specific needs. Any good idea on how to extract the Line data such as AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail so I can get cahrt of account info? That seems to be my very last hurdle.

Answer (score 2):

`var purchase = new Purchase();`

`var purchases = ds.FindAll(purchase, 0, 500);`

That's how we query our datasets. You have to repeat the query if you've got more than 500 items.